# Azure AD authentication - How to impersonate any user?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, azure-active-directory

In my current app using Asp.Net Identify, I had customized the AccountController to implement a 'God' password that could be used by an admin to login as any user.

Not the best security, but so useful to troubleshoot particular user issues.

Is there any way to do something similar when using Azure AD authentication ?

I'm using [V2 endpoint](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-appmodel-v2-overview/).

Thanks !

Comment: Instead of "God" password it is better to actually impersonate: http://tech.trailmax.info/2014/06/user-impersonation-with-asp-net-identity-2/

Comment: And no, no way to do the same for Azure AD

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not possible to impersonate a user in Azure AD without that user's credentials.